# PHP: Input time limit survey

Tags: php, input, time, limit

I would like to have a quiz with limited time for users to answer a question so they can't google. Unfortunately, this time protection can easily be bypassed if I do it with client sided languages like JavaScript.
Is there a way to do this via PHP? It should be kind of secure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save the time of last action in the session, then if time difference is `> X` print an error or have them start over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, simply tell the user they have the set time to do it, and set a session variable like so:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['to_be_completed_by'] = time() + 60;
```

As `time()` gets the current epoch time in seconds, here you're giving the user a minute. And when they submit:

```
if($_SESSION['to_be_completed_by'] <= time()){
    // Completed within the limit
}else {
    // Not completed
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!
I'm kind of new to PHP so thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION['starttime'] = time();` on the render page, then `$duration = time() - $_SESSION['starttime']` on the results page. Check if `$duration > N` (where `N` is the max duration).

This can also be coupled with javascript to alert the user their time is running low/out.

It should be noted that this would require `session_start()` to be called on the page(s).